# API Integration Test for Login controller using IdentityServer4 in aspnetcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am having issues with testing Login Controller using IdentityServer4. It throws the following error:

> {System.Net.Http.WinHttpException (0x80072EFD): A connection with the server could not be established

I am trying to generate the access Token using ResourceOwnerPassword, for which I have implemented IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator. I get the error in UserAccessToken.cs class when I call the RequestResourcePasswordAsync.
I am pretty sure it is because of the handler. Because if I use a handler in my test class and call the TokenClient with that handler I do get access Token but then I cannot test my Login Controller.

LoginController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel user)
{       
    var accessToken = await UserAccessToken.GenerateTokenAsync(user.Username, user.Password);
    var loginToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(accessToken);
    return Ok(loginToken); 
}
```

UserAccessToken.cs

```
public async Task<string> GenerateTokenAsync(string username, string password)
        {
            var tokenUrl = "http://localhost:5000/connect/token";
            var tokenClient = new TokenClient(tokenUrl,"ClientId","ClientPassword");
            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(username, password, SecurityConfig.PublicApiResourceId);
            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                throw new AuthenticationFailedException(tokenResponse.Error);
            }
            return tokenResponse.Json.ToString();

        }
```

TestClass.cs

```
 [Fact]
 public async Task Login()
 {          
     var client = _identityServer.CreateClient();
     var data = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new LoginViewModel { Username = "1206", Password = "5m{F?Hk92/Qj}n7Lp6" }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     var dd = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/login", data);
     var ss = dd;
 }
```

IdentityServerSetup.cs  //Integration Test Setup

```
public class IdentityServerSetup
{
    private TestServer _identityServer;
    private const string TokenEndpoint = "http://localhost:5000/connect/token";
    public HttpMessageHandler _handler;

    //IF I use this code I do get a AccessToken
    public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenForUser(string userName, string password, string clientId, string clientSecret, string apiName = "integrapay.api.public")
    {
        var client = new TokenClient(TokenEndpoint, clientId, clientSecret, innerHttpMessageHandler: _handler);
        var response = await client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(userName, password, apiName);
        return response.AccessToken;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have already answered the question yourself: The problem is with the `HttpHandler` the `TokenClient` uses. It should use the one provided by the `TestServer` to successfully communicate with it instead of doing actual requests to *localhost*.

Right now, `UserAccessToken` requires a `TokenClient`. This is a dependency of your class, so you should refactor the code to pass in a `TokenClient` instead of generating it yourself. This pattern is called *Dependency Injection* and is ideal for cases like yours, where you might have different requirements in your tests than in your production setup.

You could make the code look like this:

**UserAccessToken.cs**

```
public class UserAccessToken
{
    private readonly TokenClient _tokenClient;

    public UserAccessToken(TokenClient tokenClient)
    {
        _tokenClient = tokenClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> GenerateTokenAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        var tokenUrl = "http://localhost:5000/connect/token";
        var tokenResponse = await _tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(username, password, SecurityConfig.PublicApiResourceId);
        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationFailedException(tokenResponse.Error);
        }
        return tokenResponse.Json.ToString();
    }
}
```

**TestHelpers.cs**

```
public static class TestHelpers
{
    private static TestServer _testServer;
    private static readonly object _initializationLock = new object();

    public static TestServer GetTestServer()
    {
        if (_testServer == null)
        {
            InitializeTestServer();
        }
        return _testServer;
    }

    private static void InitializeTestServer()
    {
        lock (_initializationLock)
        {
            if (_testServer != null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseStartup<IntegrationTestsStartup>();
            var testServer = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
            var initializationTask = InitializeDatabase(testServer);
            initializationTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
            initializationTask.Wait();
            testServer.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
            _testServer = testServer;
        }
    }
}
```

**IntegrationTestsStartup.cs**

```
public class IntegrationTestsStartup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<TokenClient>(() =>
        {
            var handler = TestUtilities.GetTestServer().CreateHandler();
            var client = new TokenClient(TokenEndpoint, clientId, clientSecret, innerHttpMessageHandler: handler);
            return client;
        };
        services.AddTransient<UserAccessToken>();
    }
}
```

**LoginController.cs**

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserAccessToken _userAccessToken;

    public LoginController(UserAccessToken userAccessToken)
    {
        _userAccessToken = userAccessToken;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel user)
    {
        var accessToken = await _userAccessToken .GenerateTokenAsync(user.Username, user.Password);
        var loginToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(accessToken);
        return Ok(loginToken);
    }
}
```

Here's [one of my GitHub projects](https://github.com/GeorgDangl/LightQuery/blob/dev/test/LightQuery.IntegrationTestsServer/IntegrationTestServer.cs) that makes use of the `TestServer` class and shows how I'm using it. It's not using IdentityServer4, though.

Comment: Thats is good but I want to use my project startup not a mock startup.

Comment: What I do in cases like this is that I create extension methods for my project configurations. They're called from my `Startup` / `IntegrationTestStartup` class and allow me to configure a few things, for example using `TestServer` http handlers and In Memory databases instead of the real things. It is, in my opinion, a good idea to invest a bit at the beginning of a project to make sure it's easily testable and configurable. You need some way to pass different `HttpHandler`s to your method, and a separate startup class is a very simple way to do that.

Comment: I completely agree with you to have a separate startup class.But for some reason I cannot have another startup class for integration test.